# AS3 Trouble accessing ComboBox selectedItem inside MC

Tags: actionscript-3

I've created a number of MC's dynamically. Inside each MC, there are 4 comboBoxes. I'm trying to access the selectedItem.label from code.

When I use

```
trace(e.target.selectedItem.label);
```

on a mouseEvent, it gives me the right value

However, when trying to access from code on the timeline, I can't get the value e.g.

```
trace("=======================" + my_FC_row.getChildAt(4)); // Value is ComboBox
```

If I try

```
trace("=======================" + my_FC_row.getChildAt(4).selectedItem.label);
```

I get nothing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first child has index 0, try `my_FC_row.getChildAt(3)`

Comment: Tried that and got : Error #1069: Property selectedItem not found on flash.display.Shape and there is no default value - not sure what this is telling me but it seems it is not my ComboBox, which I get when the display Index is 4

Comment: It wasn't quite the right answer but it pointed me in exactly the right direction, so I'll mark it correct. Thanks